# Get data from each link in webpage to excel

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get data from the webpage.(some link)

In that webpage, there are many tickets(link) raised by customer. I need to go through each link and get some specific data from each tickets(link).

My program needs to click each review link and get some data from each link.

My program successfully picks the 1st ticket data but not all(click the 1st link and successfully get the 1st link data then it throws error).

it throws error(Access error)

Sorry my code is huge

```
Option Explicit

Sub AVS()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As HTMLDocument
Dim innerString As String
Dim ttext As Integer
Dim avsHtmlTable As Object
Dim links As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim link As Object
Dim lRow As Integer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://apj-i.svcs.hp.com/itam-av1/"

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set iedoc = ie.Document
With iedoc.forms("Login")
    .all.Item("USER").Value = "Mail id goes here"
    .all.Item("PASSWORD").Value = "pw goes here"
    .submit
End With

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

With iedoc.forms("aspnetForm")
    .all.Item("ctl00$conNavBar$acpAssets_content$btnAssets-ExceptionSearch").Click
End With

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

With iedoc.forms("aspnetForm")
    .all.Item("ctl00$conMainPageContent$txtMaxRows").Value = 100
    .all.Item("ctl00$conMainPageContent$rblStatus").Item(4).Checked = True
    .all.Item("ctl00$conMainPageContent$btnAssetExceptionSearch").Click
End With

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

With iedoc.forms("aspnetForm")
    innerString = .innerText
    ttext = InStr(innerString, "There are no results found for this query")
    If Not ttext = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no Tickets are there in AVS - Exception ", vbInformation, "AVS-Exception"
    Else
        ''ctl00_conMainPageContent_grdAssetExceptionSearchResults
        Set avsHtmlTable = iedoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each link In avsHtmlTable
            If link.innerHTML = "Review" Then
                link.Click
                Do While ie.Busy
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                With Sheets("AVS")
                set iedoc=ie.document
                    lRow = .Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
                    > ##        ' error throws here
                    Range("A" & lRow).Value = iedoc.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_ddlAssignment").Value
                End With
            End If
        Next link
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Sorry .. Not able to attach the image due to my 1st post.

Comment: You need to re-assign iedoc each time you load a new page.  Once your first page has unloaded so has the document object which iedoc references.

Comment: Could you please explain me with code...(correct me if my understanding is wrong , I need to open the each link with new ie window then close that page once macro pick the data ?)

Comment: When you load the first page you use ,`set iedoc=ie.document`. You need to repeat that for each new page you load.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question, its a bit difficult to read atm.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams ..Added your set iedoc=ie.document in my code .. it also picks the first link the data ,, throws the 'run time error - permission denied :( at 2nd time(link) ..